# How do I change my legend labels to other words?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GnQI.jpg)

I have tried several different ways, but I have had no luck so far. I am trying to change my bar chart legend labels from (0,1,2,3,4,5,6) to (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday Thursday, Friday, Saturday). Help please!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
legend_labels = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

plt.legend(labels = legend_labels, title = 'Weekdays', loc = 'upper left')
plt.show()
```